# Adding Zip codes for ad set targeting

Tags: facebook-graph-api, targeting, facebook-target-audience

I am having issue with updating targeting for adsets. As i update targeting using ZIP code against a ad set, it results in deleting of previous zip code and adding this new one zip code against the ad set. I want the previous zip codes to remain there while adding new ones.

Here is the image of API call i am using:
https://prnt.sc/q3xl6j